# List all sheets with link

Tags: excel, vba

How can create a index for all sheets automatically, I have a lot customers, with a sheet for each customer.

I also want to show some of the data in index of all the sheets.

see images
[image]

[image: images]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the sheets creating a link for each. This will list them starting at the active cell.

```
Sub CreateLinksToAllSheets()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim strLink As String

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    If ActiveSheet.name <> sh.name Then

        strLink = sh2.name
        If InStr(strLink, "'") Then
            strLink = Replace(strLink, "'", "''")
        End If

        ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & strLink & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=sh.name

        ' Here you can get the amount and mobile and write them to the adjacent columns.
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Excel.worksheetFunction.Sum(sh.Range("A:A"))
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = sh.Range("G1").Value

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    End If

Next sh

End Sub
```

If you want to hard code where the links go you can do it like this.

```
Sub CreateLinksToAllSheets()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim lRow As Long

    Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lRow = 1

    For Each sh2 In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        If ActiveSheet.name <> sh2.name AND sh2.name <> "new customer" AND sh2.name <> "old archive" Then

            strLink = sh2.name
            If InStr(strLink, "'") Then
                strLink = Replace(strLink, "'", "''")
            End If

            sh.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=sh.Range("A" & lrow), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & strLink & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=sh2.name
            sh.Range("B" & lRow).Value = Excel.worksheetFunction.Sum(sh2.Range("A:A"))
            sh.Range("C" & lRow).Value = sh2.Range("G1").Value

            lRow = lRow + 1

        End If

    Next sh2

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** OP asks
How can I make the value in column B and C Value be renewed from within sheets? Example: Column B: =SUMMA(Customer1!A:A) Column C: =Customer1!G1

You can use the formula property. Insert the sheet name from the current sh2 worksheet by using sh2.Name.

```
 sh.Range("B" & lRow).Formula = "=SUM(" & sh2.Name & "!A:A)"
 sh.Range("C" & lRow).Formula = "=" & sh2.Name & "!G1"
```

**EDIT:** OP found that creating a hyperlink to a sheet that has an apostrophe in the name does not create a functioning link.

To fix this we can add a check for the existence of an apostrophe in the sheet name. If we find one we will replace it with two apostrophes.

```
strLink = sh2.name
If InStr(strLink, "'") Then
     strLink = Replace(strLink, "'", "''")
End If
```

And change the hyperlinks.add to create SubAddress:="'" & strLink & "'"

```
sh.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=sh.Range("A" & lrow), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & strLink & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=sh2.name
```

Comment: Perfect, How can I make the value in column B and C Value be renewed from within sheets. example:
Column B:
`=SUMMA(Customer1!A:A)`
Column C:
`=Customer1!G1`
Also can more than one page exception? example: sheet name:index, AND index2, AND index3.

Comment: @Horby. See edit to my answer for you first question.

Comment: I don't follow your second question. Also can more than one page exception? Can you explain what you are looking for in a bit more detail?

Comment: I have some sheets I do not like show in index. example sheets name: `new customer` and `old archive`, it is like that.

Comment: Are you looking to skip those sheets? Not create links for them?

Comment: I have added the AND checks to the sheet name check above. If ActiveSheet.name <> sh2.name AND sh2.name <> "new customer" AND   note that these are case sensetive.  We can do it by index it you really want to but then if a sheet moves it will have issues. Let me know if that is what you needed.

Comment: Can you explain more: `We can do it by index it you really want to but then if a sheet moves it will have issues.`

I modified:`sh.Range("C" & lRow).Formula = "=" & sh2.Name & !G1"` to `sh.Range("C" & lRow).Formula = "=" & sh2.Name & "!G1"` To work well.

Comment: Sure. Index goes from 0 to x depending on how many sheets you have. So a sheet named "new customer" might be sheet(2). If a new sheet gets inserted in front of it, the sheet named "new customer" will become sheet(3). So excluding them by index could be problematic. And I will fix the edit. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Total cells do not work well. see image: http://s13.postimg.org/8aw9mtb9z/Untitled_1.jpg

Comment: change =SUMMA( to =SUM(

Comment: Really when change the order of sheets some problems happen. How can solve this problem?

Comment: What are the problems?

Comment: Note the pictures, Before changing the order: http://s15.postimg.org/tir5pj78r/Untitled_1.jpg
After changing the order:
http://s24.postimg.org/ilyquxwbp/Untitled_2.jpg

Comment: That is strange and I'm not sure even what to look at for why that would happen.  That might be a good question to start a new post.  Post the code that is creating the links and data and those two images with an explanation that you create the links then change the order and the links change.

Comment: See edit above. I assume that is the issue you are talking about because I don't see any errors when creating the hyperlink.

Comment: Thank you. Try adding a sheet that contains a name with distances.

Comment: What do you mean by distances?

Comment: I mean spaces in the name of the sheet.

Comment: I changed my sheet3 to sheet 3 and I see no issues.

Comment: Maybe issue here `sh.Range("B" & lRow).Formula = "=SUM(" & sh2.Name & "!A:A)"` And `sh.Range("C" & lRow).Formula = "=" & sh2.Name & "!G1"`

Comment: Now it works after Modified `sh.Range("B" & lRow).Formula = "=SUM('" & strLink & "'!A:A)"`
And
`sh.Range("C" & lRow).Formula = "='" & strLink & "'!G1"`