# How do I create a hyperlinked table of contents for all of my workbook sheets in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of over 100 sheet names in Column A of a sheet called "Index". Each sheet name naturally corresponds to a sheet in my workbook.

How can I hyperlink each sheet name that appears in "Index" so that I can simply access each corresponding sheet by clicking on the link?

Answer (score 0):

For more details see my answer here [List all sheets with link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32566030/list-all-sheets-with-link/32566399#32566399)

```
Sub CreateLinksToAllSheets()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim lRow As Long

    'This is the sheet we will add the links to
    Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lRow = 1

    'Loop each sheet
    For Each sh2 In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        'Make sure we are not on the current sheet or a sheet named 
        ' something we don't want to create a link for.
        If ActiveSheet.name <> sh2.name AND sh2.name <> "new customer" AND sh2.name <> "old archive" Then

            'Make sure we don't have a single quote in the sheet name.
            strLink = sh2.name
            If InStr(strLink, "'") Then
                strLink = Replace(strLink, "'", "''")
            End If

            'Create a hyperlink to that sheet.
            sh.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=sh.Range("A" & lrow), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & strLink & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=sh2.name

            lRow = lRow + 1

        End If

    Next sh2

End Sub
```